# Integer out parameter null issue in ADO.NET while calling through procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, int, out

I'm facing one issue when I try to get output value from SQL Server stored procedure which is of `INT` type, then I'm getting NULL value ☹ .

Here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.NULLISSUE 
    @input VARCHAR(10),
    @output INT = 0 OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    IF @input >= '1'
    BEGIN
        SET @output = @output + 1

        RETURN(0)
    END
END
```

Here is the .NET code:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "dbo.NULLISSUE";

        command.Parameters.Clear();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@input", "1");

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@output", SqlDbType.Int);
        command.Parameters["@output"].Value = 0;
        command.Parameters["@output"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        command.CommandTimeout = 3000;

        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();

        Console.WriteLine(command.Parameters["@output"].Value);
        //null value ?
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I have a fix by doing `ISNULL(@output, 0)` in the procedure but not sure why it can be done on the .NET side and why ADO.NET not passing/setting/initializing OUTPUT parameter = 0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your AddWithValue for output parameter, you must pass value as second parameter. You are passing SqlDbType.Int in place of value.

Comment: Also, since you want an output parameter, you don't need to set its value in ado.net code. Its value will be set automatically by your stored procedure.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @Sunil I tried before by setting up Value but it is not working I think Alex K answer should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@output` must be `ParameterDirection.InputOutput` if you want it to use the initial value set within the client.

Currently as it's `ParameterDirection.Output` the value is ignored, it defaults to `NULL` within the procedure and `NULL + anything` results in a `NULL`.